# Iterate through list in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a `.NET MVC 4` web application with the Google Maps *API*.

In this project, I have to represent several polygons over the map. The solution I came up to, is to create two tables in the `database`, one that has an identifier for each polygon, and the other saves the latitude and longitude of each corner of each polygon. Now I have to load those polygons to the map in the View.

I was trying to achieve this by loading a list in the `ViewBag`, and going through it in a script, which would represent the polygons in the map. What I send to the `ViewBag` is a `List<List<string[]>>`. Each member of the "main" list represents a polygon, which is composed by a number of markers (`List<string[]>`). In the `string[]` I save the latitude, longitude and description of each marker.

My problem now is going through such list in `Javascript`. Is that even possible? Or is there a smoother solution that I'm not contemplating?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you log the data you get by using js : console.log(viewBagData)?
I want to help you but need to see an example of the data before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is pass the data in one object to your view, and in your view, use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(polygons))`. Example below.

**C# Model:**

```
public class Polygon {
  public string Name { get; set; } // name of polygon
  public List<string> Markers { get; set; } // list of markers
}
```

**MVC Controller:**

```
List<Polygon> polygons = ...; // List of Polygons, retrieved from database

return View(polygons);
```

**Razor View:**

```
@model List<Polygon>

<script>
  var polygons = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); // will render as var polygons = [ { Name: 'Polygon1', Markers: [ 'marker1', 'marker2' ] }, { Name: 'Polygon2', Markers: [...] } ];

  // from @Kosmo's answer
  polygons.forEach(function(polygon) {
    console.log('Name is ' + polygon.Name);
    console.log('Markers are ' + polygon.Markers.join(','));
  });
</script>
```

What you end up with is a List in JSON format that is the data that's passed in from when you created it in the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
 <script>
   var arr = '@YourList`;

   arr .forEach(function(item) {
     // whatevery you want here
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's already possible if you save your ViewBag values in a variable on javascript.

you could do like this:

```
<script>
var myViewBagValue = '@ViewBag.NameOfViewBag';

//then you can iterate using one of all those ways that javascript provides

//every(), filter(), forEach(), map(), some() and etc.

</script>
```

This way your content will always be stored in a javascript value and you can manipulate without problems.